# Beautifulsoup return none value for the href how to select it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I get the hrefs from the Remixed From part on the left hand side for the following page

```
webpage = 'http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1492411'
```

I tried something like:

```
response = requests.get('http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1492411')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
remm = soup.find_all("a", class_="thing-stamp")
for rems in remm:
    adress = rems.find("href")
    print(adress)
```

Of course didn't work

EDIT: HTML tag looks like this:

```
<a class="thing-stamp" href="/thing:1430125">
<div class="stamp-content">
<img alt="" class="render" src="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/renders/57/ea/1b/cc/c2/1105df2596f30c4df6dcf12ca5800547_thumb_small.JPG"/> <div>Anet A8 button guide by Simhopp</div>
</div>
</a>
<a class="thing-stamp" href="/thing:1430727">
<div class="stamp-content">
<img alt="" class="render" src="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/renders/93/a9/c8/45/da/05fe99b5215b04ec33d22ea70266ac72_thumb_small.JPG"/> <div>Frame brace for Anet A8 by Simhopp</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
remm = soup.find_all("a", class_="thing-stamp")
for rems in remm:
    adress = rems.get('href')
    print(adress)
```